# oem oracle.sysman.top.oms ORA-01045: user SYSMAN lacks CREATE SESSION privilege;

Tags: oracle

midway through the installation of oracle enterprise manager getting the error

INFO: oracle.sysman.top.oms:java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01045: user SYSMAN lacks CREATE SESSION privilege; logon denied

a grant as below dint help

```
SQL> grant create session, connect, resource to SYSMAN;

Grant succeeded.
```

any suggestion would help

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar error setting up multiple schemas for a docker-image of Oracle XE (v21).

After creating a schema/user with:

```
CREATE USER username IDENTIFIED BY userpw;

GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE to username;
GRANT CONNECT TO username;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO username;
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO username;
GRANT CREATE any DIRECTORY TO username;
```

This was not enough to log into with this user, giving me the error.

My solution was to specify container, logging in as sysdba:

```
alter session set container=XEPDB1;

...
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO username;
...
```